# Pi Camera with multiple outputs

Tags: python, streaming-video, picamera

I am trying to stream and save video from Raspberry Pi Camera. I found code which provide streaming to HTML page but when I write output stream to a file I am getting MJPEG file which size is increasing by the time but when I watch it, I can see same image from camera for the whole time. I guess it captures just first image and then it is stuck or replicated through the whole video. I tried to write bytes when **write** method is called or when whole frame is complete but it resolves in same problem.

Here is the code. The part inside **StreamingOutput** -> `self.file.write(self.frame)` is added by me and all things about file.
(EDIT) I will be glad for any working solution not just Python.

Thank you.

```
# Web streaming example
# Source code from the official PiCamera package
# http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html#web-streaming

import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</h1></center>
<center><img src="stream.mjpg" width="90%" height=90%"></center>
</body>
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()
        self.file = None

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.file.write(self.frame)
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        #self.file.write(buf)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='1920x1080', framerate=30) as camera:
    
    try:        
        with open("/home/pi/stream.mjpeg", "wb") as outFile:
            output = StreamingOutput()
            output.file = outFile
            camera.rotation = 180
            camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
            try:
                address = ('', 8000)
                server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
                server.serve_forever()
            finally:
                camera.stop_recording()
    finally:
        outFile.close()
```

Comment: why are you limiting your chance of getting a good answer by posting here? ... the question is not about the Raspberry Pi

Comment: I am also open for other options. For example I tried even `raspivid -o - | tee file ` so it divide output to file and stdout. But tee makes video broken. Video is much short. I watch it and it is played x-times faster. I admit question is asked wrong way and thank you I also raise another in general Stack.